# SQL Trigger update another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am newbie to triggers... can anybody help me with a trigger?

I have Table:

```
Name | Number
```

I want to write a trigger when my table receives a query like

```
update MyTable 
set Number = Number + 1 
where Name = 'myname'
```

When this query is running, the trigger should update another table for example:

```
Update MyTable 2 
set Column = 'something' 
where Name = 'myname (above name)
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: i use sql server 2008

Comment: Added the `sql-server-2008` tag in that case ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to write an `UPDATE` trigger on table 1, to update table 2 accordingly.

**Be aware**: triggers in SQL Server are **not** called once per row that gets updated - they're called **once per statement**, and the internal "pseudo" tables `Inserted` and `Deleted` will contain **multiple rows**, so you need to take that into account when writing your trigger.

In your case, I'd write something like:

```
-- UPDATE trigger on "dbo.Table1"
CREATE TRIGGER Table1Updated
ON dbo.table1 FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- update table2, using the same rows as were updated in table1
    UPDATE t2
    SET t2.Column = 'something'
    FROM dbo.Table2 t2
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON t2.ID = i.ID        
END
GO
```

The trick is to use the `Inserted` pseudo table (which contains the new values after the `UPDATE` - it has the exact same structure as your table the trigger is written for - here `dbo.Table1`) in a **set-based** fashion - join that to your `dbo.Table2` on some column that they have in common (an `ID` or something).

Answer (score 1):

create a trigger on table 1 for update:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.update_trigger 
   ON  table1
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(50)
    SELECT @Name=Name FROM INSERTED
    Update MyTable 2 
        SET Column = 'something' 
        WHERE Name = @Name
END
GO
```

try this ;)

Comment: and how i can identify "where" variable?

After Begin

Comment: decalrea a variable and then "select @name=name from inserted", and in your where clause use it.need example?

Comment: This has a **fundamental flaw**! You seem to assume the trigger is called **once per row** - this is **NOT** the case with SQL Server. If your `UPDATE` affects multiple rows, the trigger will be called **once per statement**, and the pseudo tables `Inserted` and `Deleted` can contain multiple rows. So which of these rows are you selecting when doing `SELECT @Name=Name FROM INSERTED` ??? It's not defined - you get **one, arbitrary** row and all other are ignored.... you need to re-write your trigger to handle **multiple rows** in `Inserted` and `Deleted` !